# WebBrowser.Body always returns null

Tags: c#

I am trying to read and write data to open browser window in c#

For what is understand when I call webBrowser1.Document.Body all "data" in the `<body>` tag should be returned?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate("http://cs-bg.info/");
    webBrowser1.Navigated += WebBrowser1OnNavigated;
}

private void WebBrowser1OnNavigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs webBrowserNavigatedEventArgs)
{
    if (webBrowser1.Document == null)
    {
        webBrowser1.Refresh();
        return;
    }

    switch (Action)
    {
        case Action.Login:
            Login();
        break;
    }
}

private void Login()
{
    var magic = webBrowser1.Document.Body; // magic is always null
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is beacuse the document has not yet finished loading. Handle the DocumentCompleted event as below:-

```
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(IsLoadComplete);

private void IsLoadComplete(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Login();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for the WebBrowser to load target URL entirely but you cannot rely on `DocumentCompleted` event directly! this event may occur several times for a web page for any picture and other page contents.

You can check if page is ready by using `IsBusy` property:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("url");
while(webBrowser1.IsBusy)
Application.DoEvents(); //wait to document be ready
logOn(); //document is ready so do your task.
```

Or by using `ReadyState` property like above. but if you want to use `DocumentCompleted` event you should check completed URL to be same as navigated URL, not a script or picture or any thing else:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(myUri);

private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Url.AbsoluteUri != myUri)
        return;
    //else do anything
    logOn();
}
```

Comment: I like your solution about checking the URL, but you should always rely on the `DocumentCompleted` event as it's the best one for knowing when the document is fully loaded. There are always workarounds to only making it fire once/execute `Login()` once.

Comment: thanks for your note. I suggested first approach just for its simplicity.